# Вызов setState из статической функции (или другое решение)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-native

Использую `react-native-router-flux`. Для обработки нажатия правой кнопки в navigationBar определяю в классе своего компонента (сцены) `static onRight() { ... }`. Как мне из тела `onRight` вызвать `setState`, который не является статической функцией? Или же есть другое решение этой задачи?

Comment: никак: для того, чтобы вызвать метод объекта, нужен этот самый объект

Comment: а почему `onRight` стала статической? Почему `setState` не статическая?

Comment: Да, это я знаю. Но в таком случае особого смысла в этом роутере нет. Должен быть механизм взаимодействия навигационного бара с объектом, но я о нем не знаю

Comment: Это не моя архитектура) `setState` и не должна быть статической. `onRight` - понятия не имею, такова архитектура этого роутера. Не имею достаточных знаний в JS чтобы о чем-то судить :/

Comment: Может быть стоит почитать справку по роутеру, который ты хочешь использовать, перед использованием? :-) Там наверняка есть примеры

Comment: Стоит добавить [mcve], чтобы было видно, что ты вообще пытаешься делать

Comment: Навигация в React-native немного через одно место (надеюсь пока). Посмотрите подход в ответе. Суть не в том чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выполнить что-то, а уведомить компонент, что необходимо что-то выполнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки нажатия на кнопку в `NavigationBar` используте `Actions.refresh()`

Пример:

1 Настраиваете Вашу кнопку:

```
<Scene key="test" component={Test} hideNavBar={false} rightTitle="Show Alert" onRight={()=>Actions.refresh({message: "TestAlert"})}/>
```

2 Обрабатываете:

```
if(!!this.props.message) {
    alert(this.props.message)
}
```

Результат:

При нажатии на кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Показываем Alert:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете настроить как угодно под свои нужды.